# How to use Agent Forwarding from Jenkins Publish Over SSH plugin

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I have a docker deployment setup in which Jenkins runs docker-compose over an ssh connection via [Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin.

We would like to run the application containers on a private EC2 (i.e. in a private subnet), and would like to connect to it via a Bastion Host. I'm wondering how to configure the Publish Over SSH plugin to allow me to ssh into the Bastion Host, and then forward to the application server(s).
It looks like this was a [recent introduction](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/commit/cde94d8efccaaa41381df4a8950999af722b0de1), but I don't see any notes in the Change Log or instructions on the wiki page..

I am admittedly new to ssh agent forwarding, so it's possible I'm overthinking or otherwise misunderstanding something, but I was under the impression that Jenkins would need to store (at least) two sets of credentials, one for the Bastion Host and one for each private application server (I only see the single Credentials section...).

Comment: It seems like I would use a "jump host", and mention my Bastion Host's IP address. I'm wondering where I would configure the Bastion Host's user to authenticate with (it's using a different AMI than my application servers, with a different default user).

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?